# GetComponent not recognising component in Unity JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, variables, unity-game-engine

I have a code block that starts a timer, enables a script, instantiates, then disables that script (this makes my game mechanic work out). The only issue I'm facing now is my Javascript code isn't recognising a component (triggered) *error reads script as undeclared* from the public variable (which has been added, and which holds the script).

I followed the example that Unity had, and that didn't seem to work out. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code:

```
#pragma strict

var enemy : Transform;
private var timer : float;
public var mother : GameObject;

function Awake() {
    timer = Time.time + 14;
    script = mother.GetComponent(triggered);
    script.enabled = script.enabled;
}

function Update() {
    if (timer < Time.time) {
        Instantiate(enemy, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        timer = Time.time + Random.Range(55, 60);
        script.enabled = !script.enabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.You did not describe your problem. Do you get any error? What's really happening with this code? 2.`script` is not declared. Why are you trying to access/write to a variable that is not even declared? 3.You should be using C# instead of Unityscript/Javascript. You will need that if you want to create serious games in the future.

Comment: @Programmer This is my first shot at coding a game, so I'm not very experienced with which language to use ;). Yes the error was for it being undeclared, but isn't script declared as the component of mother? How could this be fixed? Would adding *private var script = mother.GetComponent(triggered);* outside and above the Awake function fix it?

Comment: You have a script called `triggered`?

Comment: @Programmer Yes, its under the game object added to the public var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `script` variable is **not** declared.

```
#pragma strict

var enemy : Transform;
private var timer : float;
public var mother : GameObject;

//DECLARE IT
private var script : triggered;

function Awake() {
    timer = Time.time + 14;
    script = mother.GetComponent(triggered);
    script.enabled = script.enabled;
}

function Update() {
    if (timer < Time.time) {
        Instantiate(enemy, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        timer = Time.time + Random.Range(55, 60);
        script.enabled = !script.enabled;
    }
}
```

Note:

Please [learn](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/scripting) C# and start using it in Unity. You will save yourself your time. Also, when creating scripts make sure to capitalize them. For example, `triggered` should be `Triggered`.

Comment: Huge noob mistake, damn it. I'll take your word and be sure to learn my Cs if I decide to continue using Unity. Thank you!