# Is Unityscript/Javascript discontinued?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am using *Unity 2017.2.0b5*. I tried to help somebody who asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45522630/getcomponent-not-recognising-component-in-unity-javascript-code) about Unityscript few moments ago but I noticed that:

**Assets > Create > C# Script** is present but **Assets > Create > JavaScript** is missing.

This is also missing from the Project tab and the Create new script menu which is on the Add Component menu.

I read the release note but couldn't find anything about Unityscript/Javascript.

Has Unity just killed Unityscript/JavaScript support like Boo?

Comment: No sane person would use UnityScript, you should be on C#.... Unity made a mess by releasing their own mutation of Javascript; so I'd like if it *is* recinded but I've read nothing about that happening. You should probably ask this question on [GameDev Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) or [Unity Developers Forum](https://forum.unity3d.com/)

Comment: @Martin I don't think this question is any more relevant over on Game Dev (it's got [similar posting rules to SO](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), anything off-topic on SO would be off-topic on GD), but the Unity Developers Forum would be an ideal place. The general advice is: before asking, always check the site's how to ask page.  Programmer: I wouldn't be surprised if they killed off the monocompiler. It's really held Unity back from taking advantage of newer .NET features, like covariance and contravariance.

Comment: @Draco18s Unity forum is not very active. I will ask there too. I just wanted to know if any one here has any idea if this has been killed off or maybe this is a bug. I wonder why Unity would remove it without even mentioning it on their blog or release note. I now suspect it has been killed.

Comment: @Martin Many people still do because they came from web development background. Although, I don't and have been encouraging them to switch to C#.

Comment: "[UnityScript has already been abandoned. Just no one has told the marketing team yet.](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-and-javascript.458184/#post-2973333)"

Comment: That's interesting. I knew they were going to when they released their C# vs Javascript usage poll in 2014 but not unannounced like this.

Comment: @Draco18s Not sure if I should delete this or maybe you should make that an answer so that any Unityscript question will be linked to this post.

Comment: Its the only source and it's not even terribly official (and from 6 months ago). Heck, two replies down is a Unity rep saying they aren't yanking it just yet (and a little later on: the UnityScript compiler is apparently written in Boo, so axing one takes out the other). I can turn that into an answer if you'd like, but it feels so unsatisfactory.

Comment: @Draco18s Unity finally replied to another user [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/is-unityscript-javascript-discontinued.486824/#post-3174123). You can quote that as answer. It looks like you can just drag Javascript file there but you can't create new one from Unity itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to some comments on the Unity forums:

One user said back in February, "[UnityScript has already been abandoned. Just no one has told the marketing team yet.](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-and-javascript.458184/#post-2973333)"

Then just today (at the time of this post), a Unity representative replied, 
"[UnityScript will continue to work in 2017.2. **We removed the menu item because we would like to avoid new users picking it up,** but you can still add new UnityScript files to your project by other means](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/is-unityscript-javascript-discontinued.486824/#post-3174123)" (emphasis mine).

So there we have it. UnityScript is (likely) being removed and this is the first step: preventing new users from starting with it.

Comment: A more detailed blog post official response: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/08/11/unityscripts-long-ride-off-into-the-sunset/

Comment: @MollyJ awesome, thanks for the link, looks like initial preceptions were accurate: it was being depreciated but the marketing team hadn't yet been told/written up a press release.