# Read mouse click Input.GetMouseDown with Unityscript

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I try to get on the mouse down work, I have find a example but its not work 
this is my error
Assets/scripts/onclickx.js(13,5): BCE0044: expecting EOF, found '}'.

This is my code

```
import UnityEngine.UI;
import UnityEngine.EventSystems;



if(Input.GetMouseDown(0){
   // Whatever you want it to do.
   ScoreSystem.drinks -= 1;

   mySlider = GameObject.Find("water").GetComponent(UnityEngine.UI.Slider);
   counter.water = counter.water += 10
  mySlider.value = counter.water; 
}
```

this is the script for the counter.js

```
import UnityEngine.UI;
var mySlider: UnityEngine.UI.Slider;
var water = 90;
function Start () {
  // substitute 'sliderName' with the literal name 
  // of your slider as it appears in the hierarchy:
  mySlider = GameObject.Find("water").GetComponent(UnityEngine.UI.Slider);
  mySlider.value = water; 
  }


 function OnTriggerEnter(other : Collider) 
 {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        ScoreSystem.drinks += 1;
        mySlider.value += 10; 
  // insert desired variable here in place of 'n'
  // slider will automagically adjust to display new value
  }
```

and this is the code for my score system

```
static var myScore = 0;
static var score = 0;
static var money = 0;
static var level = 0;
static var drinks = 0;


public var guiSkin : GUISkin;




function OnGUI()
{
 GUI.skin = guiSkin;

GUI.contentColor = Color.green;

GUI.Label(Rect((Screen.width / 2) - 60,15, 200, 30), "Score: " + score);
GUI.Label(Rect((Screen.width / 2) - 60,30, 200, 30), "Money: " + money);
GUI.Label(Rect((Screen.width / 2) - 60,42, 200, 30), "Level: " + level);
GUI.Label(Rect((Screen.width / 2) - -320,25, 200, 30), "Drinks: " + drinks);

}
```

Comment: I forgot to tell you something after answering your last question. UnityScript/Javascript is [no longer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45536613/3785314) supported. The compiler will be removed soon. You have to [learn](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/scripting) and start using C#.

Comment: As for your problem, you need to add another `)` before the `{`.  Also that code in the `if` statement should be inside a function. It's not inside a function right now.

Comment: @Programmer can you please give me an example

Comment: Sure I will but won't in the future if you keep asking js questions with Unity. Your counter variable is not declared too. What is the name of that class?

Comment: the script class is counter.js counter.water --> water = variable

Comment: Is the water a static variable? It is better to post that script too.

Comment: @Programmer  Yes it his a static variable

Comment: You gotta be start to learn C# because c# is 4x faster than javaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are just many issues with your first code.

**1**.The code is not inside a function. That should be in the `Update` function.

**2**.You are missing extra `)` in the `if` statement since there should be one `)` for the `GetMouseDown` function and another one that closes the `if` statement.

**3**.The `mySlider` variable is not declared. You manged to declare that in the `counter` script but not in your first script.

```
import UnityEngine.UI;
import UnityEngine.EventSystems;

var mySlider:Slider;

function Update(){

    if(Input.GetMouseDown(0)){
        // Whatever you want it to do.
        ScoreSystem.drinks -= 1;

        mySlider = GameObject.Find("water").GetComponent(UnityEngine.UI.Slider);
        counter.water = counter.water += 10;
        mySlider.value = counter.water; 
    }
}
```

---

Note:

It is always good to capitalize the first letter in your class/script name. For example, `counter` should be `Counter` and your variable names should start with lower-case. This will make it easier for people to read and understand your code.

Finally, convert all your scripts to [C#](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/scripting). You will have to do this ASAP so that you won't have to restart your project over again when the Unityscript compiler is removed.

Comment: Tanks for the help i have make a new script for the score system but in c# so now i will remake all js in to c# its sounds more easy

Comment: Yes. I suggest you do that now that you have few scripts.