# Trying to get the script of another class in unity with javascript

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, raycasting

My Raycast is working and hitting my Enemy.

But if I hit him, I want to change the health variable in the other script of the hit Object (Enemy Controller) by calling the `TakeDamage(damage)` function.

Unfortunately, I get this error:

> "Assets/Weapons/FPS Weapons/Scripts/Gun_Controller.js(692,35): BCE0018: The name 'EnemyController' does not denote a valid type ('not
>   found'). Did you mean 'System.ComponentModel.EnumConverter'?"

Here's my Code:

```
if (hit.transform.tag == "warzombie_01") {

    // Impact Particle for Enemy - warzombie_01
    var impactHitBlood: GameObject = Instantiate(impactEffectBlood, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));

    Destroy(impactHitBlood, 0.5 f);

    //var enemyController : EnemyController = hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent.<EnemyController>();

    var enemyController: EnemyController = hit.transform.GetComponent(EnemyController);

    if (enemyController != null) {

        enemyController.TakeDamage(damage);
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is JavaScript? Or does Unity enforce types in JS? -- Ah. You might want to add the `UnityScript` tag.

Comment: It is still some kind of Javascript but UnityScript tag is better used for this.

Comment: @1zz0, This problem only happens with UnityScript. Consider switching to C#. Another reason to switch to C# is because UnityScript is now [discontinued](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45523239/is-unityscript-javascript-discontinued). Its compiler will be removed from Unity in the future. Save yourself time now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found out the problem. My "Enemy Controller" should be in the following folder: Assets > Standard Assets.

Comment: Did you want to close the question, or wait and mark this as the answer? (Either way, you won't get an rep )