# Can I use Java script language in Unity3d 2017.2?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I notice that in MonoDevelop editor the auto correction for javascript it doesn't work .
Does this mean that Unity is willing to abandon JS ?
Can I use Java script language in Unity 2017.2 ?

Comment: _the Unity 2017.2 beta no longer has a ‘Javascript’ (a.k.a UnityScript) option in the Create Assets menu_ . What i know is it will deprecate. Maybe it already has. You can read the [blog](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/08/11/unityscripts-long-ride-off-into-the-sunset/) about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, you can still use it in Unity 2017.2. The menu to create a Javascript script is **gone**. You have to create a Javascript file with an external file Editor like Notepad then drag it into your Unity project and it should just work. It should have *.js* extension.

Note that Unity is in the process of stripping the Javascript compiler out of Unity Editor so you won't be able to use Javascript in the future. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45523239/is-unityscript-javascript-discontinued) post for more information.

Comment: thanks @Programmer .... i am a beginner in unity , do you advise me to learn c# with unity ?

Comment: It was a problem to learn C# with Unity in the past but now Unity put a C# tutorial with Unity which is very easy and helpful. Start from [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/scripting).  After that I suggest you learn C# from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/) to cover some things you missed.